# socket.io don't support express3?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I started to learn socket.io and express3 but I found that when I do this -

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

It writes to the console that `express.createServer()` is deprecated.

I googled about it but couldn't find any answers for that..what should I do?
Maybe I should downgrade express or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a close look at the [documentation](http://socket.io/#how-to-use). You'll see that there is a key difference between using socket.io in the section: "Using with the Express 3 web framework" vs "Using with the Express web framework". The example they give is:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

Just follow that pattern and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

lokking at [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html)you need to change the `var app = require('express').createServer()`

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```